# Making one letter in a string lowercase and all other letters uppercase

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a variable string uppercase and one letter that is in () lower case. string will be what ever the user enters so do not know what it will be ahead of time.

user entry examples

What is entered

```
hello(K)
```

what is expected outcome

```
HELLO(k)
```

What is entered

```
(K)lear
```

what is expected outcome

```
(k)LEAR
```

here is what i have tried but can only get it to work if the () are at the end of the string.

```
    if(getElementById("ID")){
        var headline = getElementById("ID").getValue();
        var headlineUpper = headline.toUpperCase();
        var IndexOf = headlineUpper.indexOf("(");
        if(IndexOf === -1){
            template.getRegionNode("Region").setValue(headlineUpper);
        }
        else{
            var plus = parseInt(IndexOf + 1);
            var replacing = headlineUpper[plus];
            var lower = replacing.toLowerCase();
            var render = headlineUpper.replace(headlineUpper.substring(plus), lower + ")");
            
            getElementById("Region").setValue(render);
        }
    }
```

Do to our system i am only able to use vanilla javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the three parts of the string separately.

```js
const convert = str => {
  let idx = str.indexOf('(');
  if(idx === -1){
    return str.toUpperCase();
  } else {
    return str.slice(0, idx).toUpperCase() + str.slice(idx, idx + 3).toLowerCase() + str.slice(idx + 3).toUpperCase();
  }
};
console.log(convert('hello(K)'));
console.log(convert('(K)lear'));
```

Comment: @logan No problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression replacement, along with a function to calculate the replacement from the capture groups.

```js
function convertParenCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/^([^(]*)(\([^)]*\))(.*)/,
    (match, g1, g2, g3) => g1.toUpperCase() + g2.toLowerCase() + g3.toUpperCase());
}

console.log(convertParenCase('hello(K)'));
console.log(convertParenCase('(K)lear'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easily with regular expression.

```
if(getElementById("ID")){
    var headline = getElementById("ID").getValue();
    var headlineUpper = headline.toUpperCase();
    var textInBracket = headlineUpper.match(/\(.*\)/);
    if(textInBracket && textInBracket.length) {
       headlineUpper = headlineUpper.replace(textInBracket[0], textInBracket[0].toLowerCase())
    }
    template.getRegionNode("Region").setValue(headlineUpper);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let x = 'hello(K)'
x.toUpperCase().replace(/\(.+\)/g, x.match(/\(.+\)/g)[0].toLowerCase())
```

You can convert everything to the capital case then using pattern matching replace the string inside the parenthesis to lower case (sort of a hack)

and for cases where you may or may not get the parenthesis:

```
x.toUpperCase().replace(/\(.+\)/g, (x.match(/\(.+\)/g)?x.match(/\(.+\)/g)[0]:"").toLowerCase())
```